# Please do these series diverge or converge and find their sums if they converge

Tags: convergence-divergence

a) $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{-2k+1}$$            b) $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{2k+1}$$

my Trial

a) $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{-2k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{-3}{9^k}$$

I am blocked because I wanted to have it in the form $ar^n$ and later us

Comment: $a=-3, r=1/9$  You've done it.

Comment: No, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{-2k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{-3}{9^k}$$ is incorrect.  Should be $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{-2k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3}{9^k}$$

Comment: These questions really boil down to pre calc exponent properties if you pretend the summation symbol isn’t there..

Comment: @AlioBadi Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{-2k+1}=3\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac19\right)^k$

and

- $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{2k+1}=3\sum_{k=1}^\infty 9^k$

Answer (score 0):

For a), $r=1/9$; for b), $r=9$. So b) diverges, but... well, I'll let you work out a).